# How to get just one column of a DataSet?

Tags: c#, dataset

I have information for an application stored in a DataSet. Table 0 of the dataset (accessed by DataSet.Tables[0]) has a column called "Station ID". I need to get a dataset that has just this column in it.

How do I get fill a new DataSet with all Station IDs?

Comment: There might be a convenient linq way to do it, but outside of that you'll need to just create a second dataset, put a datatable in it with that one column, and then copy it row by row.

Comment: @BlargleMonster - that's what I was figuring. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new `DataSet` with a `DataTable` that has your column and copy the rows:

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(oldDt.Columns["StationID"]);

        for (int i = 0; i < oldDt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows[i]["StationID"] = oldDt.Rows[i]["StationID"];
        }
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Alternatively, you can clone the current datatable and remove the columns you don't need:

```
        DataTable dt = oldDt.Copy();
        dt.Columns.Remove("Column1");
        dt.Columns.Remove("Column2");
        //...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
public DataSet DataSetStationId(DataSet yourDataSet) 
    {
        DataSet newDs = new DataSet();

        DataTable newDt = new DataTable();

        newDt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Station Id"));

        for (int i = 0; i < yourDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++) 
        {
            newDt.Rows[i]["Station Id"] = yourDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Station Id"];
        }

        newDs.Tables.Add(newDt);

        return newDs;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a single value and you know the Row Number:

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 DataTable dt = new DataTable()
 int StationID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.dt.[RowID][StationID])
```